# Exception when upgrade to Hibernate 4.2.3

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have this exception when upgrade from hibernate 4.0.1Final to 4.2.3Final (actually it happens for all versions from 4.1.6):

```
16:46:19,946 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1) javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
16:46:19,948 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1) at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
16:46:19,949 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1) at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310)
16:46:19,959 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1) at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:275)

......

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "PROCESSWIT0_"."SUBSCR_ID": invalid identifier
```

This have worked before. I think the issue happens because we use inheritance:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PROCESS_WITH_ACTION")
public abstract class ProcessWithAction extends SimpleProcess {...}

@MappedSuperclass
public class SimpleProcess extends BusinessProcess {...}

@Entity
@Table(name = "PROCESS")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class BusinessProcess extends Identifiable {...}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Identifiable implements Serializable, IValidatable {
    @ManyToOne(optional=false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="SUBSCR_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false, nullable=false)
    private Subscriber subscriber;
    ...
}
```

So when I query for the list of ProcessWithAction by using getResultList() that exception happens. I also try to change inheritance strategy to SINGLE_TABLE and TABLE_PER_CLASS, but all of them do not work as before (version 4.0.1Final).

I do not have any ideas to fix it. Could you please give me some advices.

Thanks

Comment: What does your [hibernate SQL log](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging) say?

Comment: I just look at the SQL query generated by hibernate 4.2.3, there is PROCESSWIT0_.SUBSCR_ID in the query(SUBSCR_ID does not exist in PROCESS_WITH_ACTION table, it's only in PROCESS table). When I change back to 4.0.1Final, there is no PROCESSWIT0_.SUBSCR_ID in the query. So I think hibernate 4.2.3 change the way to generate SQL. But I still cannot resolve the issue.